# Show button back on its position

Tags: android, onclick, textview

consider a two textview and button with letter O. On clicking both button textview fills with both letter O making button invisible, vice versa consider that onclick textview both textview sets empty value and the button restores back to its position but problem is only one button gets visible. here is a sample code

```
if(t1.getText().toString()==b9.getText().toString()){
  t1.setText("");
  position--;
  b9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 
else if(t1.getText().toString()==b10.getText().toString()){
  t1.setText("");
  position--;
  b10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(t1.getText().toString()==b9.getText().toString()){
```

**==** is not to be used for checking if text is equal

you should be using

```
String text1 = t1.getText().toString();
String text2 = b9.getText().toString();
    if(text1.equalsIgnoreCase(text2){
```

== is used to check the address of the object.. not the text contents

Answer (score 0):

try removing else, just do it in separate "if()s".

At the moment only one of them is being executed.